# How to initialize fields for an unknown generic type

Tags: typescript, generics, initialization

I'm learning about type manipulation in TypeScript and thought I'd try to make a type-safe function for converting between arrays-of-structs and structs-of-arrays.

My attempt is below, but I'm running into an issue with instantiating the struct-of-arrays. I need to initialize it, but I don't know how. If I don't then I can't push values to the arrays.

I could use `any` for the type of `soa`, but that would defeat the purpose of the exercise.

```
type SoA<Object> = { [Key in keyof Object]: Object[Key][] };
type AoS<Object> = { [Key in keyof Object]: Object[Key] }[];

function aos2soa<Type>(aos: AoS<Type>): SoA<Type> {
    let soa: SoA<Type> = {}; // Error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'SoA<Type>'.

    for (const struct of aos) {
        let key: keyof Type;
        for (key in struct) {
            soa[key].push(struct[key]);
        }
    }
    return soa;
}
```

Is there a type-safe way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

TS compiler is not able to typecast empty json to `SoA`. Try this

```
const soa: SoA<Type> = {} as SoA<Type>;
```

As for getting it working, tested this on ts playground. Is this what you are looking for

```
type SoA<Object> = { [Key in keyof Object]: Object[Key][] };
type AoS<Object> = { [Key in keyof Object]: Object[Key] }[];

function aos2soa<Type>(aos: AoS<Type>): SoA<Type> {
  const soa: SoA<Type> = {} as SoA<Type>;

  for (const struct of aos) {
    for (const key in struct) {
      if(!soa[key]){
        soa[key] = []
      }
      soa[key].push(struct[key]);
    }
  }
  return soa;
}

type User = {
  name: string;
  id: number
}

const users: AoS<User> = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'pqr'
  }
]

const output: SoA<User> = aos2soa(users)
console.log(output)
```

The output being

```
[LOG]: {
  "id": [
    1,
    2
  ],
  "name": [
    "abc",
    "pqr"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't address the initialization issue. How can I initialize the inner arrays if I don't know their property names?

Comment: added an attempt to the solution.. let me know if this is what you are looking for.. if not do elaborate more